# Extracting tuples from tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples

Given `(a, b, (c, d, e, f), g)`how can I extract `(c, d, e, f)`automatically? ( not by explicitly extracting the variables one by one and adding them to a list or something)

Comment: Not really sure what this is asking, but you can index a tuple that is an element of another tuple just like you would index any other element in a tuple.  In this case `x[2]`.  Tuples don't care what the types are of their elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the first tuple from a list, just do:

```
tup = ('a', 'b', ('c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), 'g')
# Get first tuple
print (_ for _ in tup if type(_) is tuple).next()
# ('c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract all tuple-valued items inside a tuple, you can use the [filter() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) in a one-liner:

```
filter(lambda a: isinstance(a, tuple), yourEnclosingTuple)
```

If you want that specific one you have shown, it is as simple as this if you want a specific one:

```
>>> x = (1, 2, (3,4,5,6), 7)
>>> x[2]
  (3, 4, 5, 6)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this little recipe will help. It uses Python 3.4 syntax however, and makes use of generators and generator delegation.

```py
def flatten(iterator):
    for item in iterator:
        if hasattr(item, "__iter__") and not isinstance(item, str):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item

print(list(flatten((1, "2", (3, 4, (5, 6), 7), 8.0, (9, 10), 11))))
# [1, '2', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.0, 9, 10, 11]
```

Simply put: the function creates a generator that will yield each element if they are single. If one element is iterable (has `__iter__` attribute), it uses a recursion to yield elements inside the iterable element.

For a Python 2 compatible generator, you can use:

```py
def flatten(iterator):
    for item in iterator:
        try:
            it = iter(item)
        except TypeError:
            yield item
        else:
            if not isinstance(item, basestring):
                for inner_item in flatten(item):
                    yield inner_item
            else:
                yield item

print list(flatten((1, "2", (3, 4, (5, 6), 7), 8.0, (9, 10), 11)))
# [1, '2', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.0, 9, 10, 11]
```

*Note the special handling of strings, that may not be necessary for you (because a string can be iterated into strings of one character at a time, but this produced string can also be iterated, etc...).*

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you mean for Python 2 ? Yes, that would be another way to do. For Python 3, I do not see the point in importing a module, the result is the same and the code as readable.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I must argue against. I agree that creating the `it` may add some overhead, but compared to the code involved in checking that a class is or isn't a subclass of Iterable, I object that it is lighter. Concerning `hasattr`, I think [this](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/97ef38236dc1/Lib/_collections_abc.py#l88) closes the discussion :)

Comment: Please go ahead, and propose your answer.